# format date from excel to dd-Mmm-yyyy to Python

Tags: python, excel

I have pulled date from excel to python , when I print the date is shows like "2019-11-28 00:00:00" . I want to again pass this date to python program in format 24-Nov-2019.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(VAR-WITH-THE-DATE)
print date.strftime('%d, %b %Y')
```

Take a look at the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to see further information.

Comment: Got this error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:xxxxxxxxxxxxxpy", line 18, in <module>
    date = datetime.datetime(expdate.value)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
2019-11-28 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do the job:

```py
from datetime import datetime
def excel_to_formatted_date(input_date):
    return datetime.fromisoformat(input_date).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

Testing with your value gives the following:

```
>>> excel_to_formatted_date('2019-11-28 00:00:00')
'28-Nov-2019'
```

Please note that the `%b` format code will use the current locale (i.e. the month name will be translated according to the current locale)

Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information on `datetime`'s format codes.